# Android action chooser - how to handle intents inside the Activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

I've the following statement in my `Manifest.xml`:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.app.SelectLinks">

        <intent-filter>

        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.OPEN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="file" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.pls" />

        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

My app appears in the action chooser when I try to open the .pls file. The problem is I'don't know how to handle this on the Activity's site. Any examples appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the activity call `getIntent()`. It returns an `Intent` object that started the activity.

You can obtain the data and other information from the intent by calling its methods such as `getAction()`, `getType()`, `getData()`, `getCategories()` and `getExtras()`.

See `Intent` [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) for more information.

Note that if the `launchMode` of the activity is `singleTop`, implement `onNewIntent()` callback, there the intent is passed as a parameter. More about that [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29).